# Restriction of files types don't work

Tags: jquery, blueimp

I used such regex found in some example.In Opera it allows me to upload PDF but not PSD and EPS on the other hand  in Firefox only images like jpg,png, gif no possibility of upload EPS no PDF no PSD. i use blueimp upload plugin. The regex seems ok why it doesnt allow all the types and moreover in one browser i can upload at least pdf type and in other nothing besides typical image

what should be correct regex to include listed files types?

```
     var acceptFileTypes =  /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|eps|tiff|cdr)$/i;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add them to the regex?

Answer (score 0):

just add extensions to regex:

```
var acceptFileTypes =  /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|eps|tiff|cdr|eps|psd)$/i;
```

not to sure what you mean by

> ...in Firefox only images like jpg,png, gif no EPS no PDF no PSD

when PDF is in the original regex. do you mean in firefox PDF upload wasn't working

Comment: this regex doesnt work as it should; in opera it accepts pdf and in firefox not.Both dont accept psd eps despite the fact i have it in this regex

Comment: well the regex works for me in firefox, it matches everything asked of it. maybe its the plugin

Comment: i should add that i outputted to console.log, ie the regex matches as expected. how the plugin will handle it is a different matter, i can't help there, but the regex is valid as far as i'm concerned